# C++. From file to function, cin in main

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Jung
{

public:
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
    int c4;
    int c5;
    int c6;
    friend Jung operator+(Jung n1, Jung l1);
    friend Jung operator*(Jung n2, Jung l2);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &in, Jung n);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &out, Jung &n);

};

Jung operator+(Jung n1, Jung l1){
     Jung nuoseklus;
     nuoseklus.c5=(1/((1/n1.c1)+(1/n1.c2)+(1/n1.c3)));
     return nuoseklus;
}
Jung operator*(Jung n2, Jung l2){
    Jung lygiagretus;
    lygiagretus.c6=n2.c4;
    return lygiagretus;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &in, Jung &n){
    in >> n.c1>>n.c2>>n.c3>>n.c4;
    return  in;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Jung n){
    out << n.c5<<n.c6;
    return out;
}
int main() {
    Jung n,i,j;
    ifstream myfile("TadasVagonis_EIf_14-2_variantas_03.txt");
    cin>>i.c5>>j.c6;
    n=i+j;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a file, i need to read 4 numbers from it, use it in functions operator+ and operator*. The formulas in first function is good, in operator* i just need it to have c4 value. My final answer should be value from operator+ added to value of operator*. Sry for bad english, its hard to explain.

Comment: Right now in cmd i get nothing.

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described [here in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

the signatures are wrong for the outside function.

it should be

```
Jung Jung::operator+(Jung RHS){
...
}

Jung Jung::operator*(Jung RHS){
...
}
```

and so on.

after that try. Hope you will achieve what you want

Comment: But then Jung Jung::operator+(Jung, Jung) must take either zero or no argument

Comment: so @user3088057 have you achieved your goal ?

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get what you mean by RHS

Comment: RHS is "Right Hand Side" ... what I want to tell you is RHS object will be a copy of the object which will be present on the right hand side of the operator. :)

Comment: I have failed to achieve anything, but thanks for you time :) Im new to programming. Im basically im stupid :D

Comment: he he @user3088057.. you can ask me if can help ?

Comment: Did you understand what I want to do? Because if you didnt you cant help :) If you did, can you give me the part that needs to be changed in program. I really dont understand how to use your suggestion :)

Comment: I understand what you want .. it is known as operator overloading. I can surely help you out for this. and tell you some concept also.

Comment: class Jung
{

public:
    int c1;
    int c2;
};

Answer (score 0):

please compile the code and try to understand the comment give for specific line and rest of your program you can implement.

```
class Jung
    {    
    public:
        int c1, c2;
        Jung()
        {
          // defult constroctor
        }; 
        Jung(int tempa, int tempb)
        {
            c1 = tempa;
            c2 = tempb;
        }

        //now we will do operator overloading
        Jung operator+(Jung RHS)
        {
            c1 = RHS.c1;
            c2 = RHS.c2;
            return (*this); // read more about this pointer
        }
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &myOut, Jung &Rhs); // to inform the class thta this is a frind function    
};

    ostream& operator<< (ostream &myOut, Jung &Rhs)
    {
        myOut<<"value for C1 is :"<<Rhs.c1;
        myOut<<"\nValue for C2 is :"<<Rhs.c2;
        return myOut;   
    }

int main()
{
    Jung obj1(10,20);
    Jung obj2(30,40);
    Jung obj3;
    obj3 = obj1 + obj2; //Jung operator+(Jung RHS) will get called
    cout<<obj3; // ostream &operator<<(ostream &myOut, Jung &Rhs) will get called
    return 0;
}
```